# Function onCreate not execute on activity start Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development and I just started learning.

Here's my problem:

My `onCreate` function in `activity_main` works normally, it shows everything. Then he logs in and shows me the second activity and there also the `onCreate` function works but when I go to the third activity the `onCreate` function does not execute.

DashboardActivity.kt

```
class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
        val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
       sendGet()
       // sendPostRequest()
    }
fun openTest(view: View){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }
}
```

TestActivity.kt

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        println("test")
    }
}
```

Could someone guide me or explain what and how? I've been sitting on this for a while, searching the internet and nothing...

I searched the internet, tried solutions, tried to create more activities, turned on debug mode by adding breakpoint and it doesn't even enter this function

Comment: Try log `Log.d("test");`, `println` doesn't work in some devices.

Comment: Which Activity is the third one? And how are you starting it? If you are trying to start an activity by calling `setContentView()` that doesn’t make sense. `setContentView` loads a new view for the current activity. It doesn’t start a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start an Activity, you need to call the following:

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java))
```

Otherwise, `onCreate(Bundle?)` will not be called if you do not explicitly call the above.

So in your case, seems that you would like to get to `TestActivity` in `openTest(View)`, you should have something like this:

```kotlin
fun openTest(view: View) {
  startActivity(Intent(this, TestActivity::class.java))
  // Calling setContentView() will not trigger another Activity
  // setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}
```

Comment: Okey thanks, that's working now but I'm don't know how that was working on previous activity... I'm gonna change this. Thanks you :D